# How to make equation spacing consistent in minipage regardless of horizontal alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, amsmath

Under ordinary circumstances with `amsmath`, when I wrap display equations in a minipage, they appear without any `\abovedisplayskip` spacing if the equation appears first in the minipage but with the ordinary spacing if it appears in the middle. This is the behavior I want.

The problem I'm having comes from trying to have a configurable alignment for the minipage. If I use `\raggedright` (or `\RaggedRight`), the vertical spacing continues to work as expected. However, if I start the minipage with a `\centering` command, the full amount of `\abovedisplayskip` is inserted.

I realize that issuing a centering command right before display math seems redundant, but I'm trying to set up macros that will do the right thing for the user in a wide variety of circumstances. So how can I set up things so that the vertical space will not appear if `\centering` happens to be the setting right before the equation?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\myformat}{\raggedright}

\newcommand{\qbar}{%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=black!30,minimum width=\linewidth] {};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par\addvspace{4pt}
}

\newcommand{\stimulus}[1]{
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \myformat#1
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

ragged right

\qbar
\stimulus{Here is some random text with a 
  \[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  display equation in the middle of it.}

\qbar
\stimulus{\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\columnbreak
\renewcommand{\myformat}{\centering}

centering

\qbar
\stimulus{Here is some random text with a 
  \[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  display equation in the middle of it.}

\qbar
\stimulus{\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]

  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In short, I would like the minipage at bottom right to have the same vertical alignment as the one to its left.

[image]

Comment: unrelated but the underfull hbox with badness 1000 are due to the nissing `%` at ends of lines in your definition of `\stimulus`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically TeX does not support starting a paragraph with display math, if you attempt that it always forces a spurious "white" paragraph above the display that looks like vertical space but is in fact a paragraph line, so is not dropped like white space at the start of a page for example.

In the usual case the white line just has indentation box and `\parfillskip` glue so the display starts with `\abovedisplayshortskip` but with `\centering` the non-zero `\leftskip` means that the white line is seen as being long so the display is preceded with the (typically larger) `\abovedisplayskip`.

You can get more consistent spacing if you prefix with `\noindent`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\showoutput
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\myformat}{\raggedright}

\newcommand{\qbar}{%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=black!30,minimum width=\linewidth] {};  
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par\addvspace{4pt}
}

\newcommand{\stimulus}[1]{%
  \noindent\setbox0\hbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \myformat#1
  \end{minipage}}\showbox0\box0
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

ragged right

\qbar
\stimulus{\noindent\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\columnbreak
\renewcommand{\myformat}{\centering}

centering

\qbar
\stimulus{\noindent\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\useshortskip` command from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\myformat}{\raggedright}

\newcommand{\qbar}{%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=black!30,minimum width=\linewidth] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par\addvspace{4pt}
}

\newcommand{\stimulus}[1]{
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \myformat#1
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

ragged right

\qbar
\stimulus{Here is some random text with a
  \[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  display equation in the middle of it.}

\qbar
\stimulus{\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]%
  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\columnbreak
\renewcommand{\myformat}{\centering}

centering

\qbar
\stimulus{Here is some random text with a
\[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  display equation in the middle of it.}

\qbar
\stimulus{ \useshortskip \[y = \frac{3}{2}x^2 + 2x -10\]
  \noindent Here is some random text with a
  display equation above it.}

\end{multicols}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good every answers for this question.+1