# Overfull hbox with parindent, tcolorbox and witharrows

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox, warnings, parindent, witharrows

As per the title, I get an overfull hbox whenever I utilize a combination of a tcolorbox with a non-zero parindent and a DispWithArrows environment. I've not tried particularly much as I don't see what could be there to change/influence as the problem persists even with the minimal combination of the three items mentioned above.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\overfullrule=1mm

\usepackage{witharrows,tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[before upper*={\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}}]
     \begin{DispWithArrows*}
         & 2 + 2 \\ {}={} & 4
     \end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark**:

`witharrows` v2.6d 2022-01-01 (see [diff in texlive's svn repo](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/witharrows/witharrows.sty?r1=61449&r2=61448&pathrev=61449)) has fixed this issue, so you don't need the following `\AtBeginEnvironment` patch.

**Original Answer**:

Prepending a `\noindent` to `\begin{DispWithArrows*}` does the trick. You can make it automatically inserted by using

```tex
\AtBeginEnvironment{DispWithArrows*}{\ifvmode\noindent\fi}
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows,tcolorbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{DispWithArrows*}{\ifvmode\noindent\fi}
\overfullrule=1mm

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[before upper*={\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}}]
     \noindent\begin{DispWithArrows*}
         & 2 + 2 \\ {}={} & 4
     \end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Btw, it's reproducible with `DispWithArrows(*)` + `minipage` but not with `align` + `minipage`, so there's some improvements `witharrows` can do. Perhaps in

```tex
% witharrows.sty v2.6c 2021/03/04
\NewDocumentEnvironment { DispWithArrows } { ! d < > ! O { } }
  {
    % ...
    % lines 1093--1101
    \bool_if:NTF \l__witharrows_in_label_or_minipage_bool
      { \c_math_toggle_token }
      {
        \if_mode_vertical:
        \nointerlineskip % <<< possible position
        \hbox_to_wd:nn { .6 \linewidth } { }
        \fi:
        \c_math_toggle_token \c_math_toggle_token
      }
    % ...
  }
```

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\overfullrule=1mm

\begin{document}
\verb|minipage| starts with a \verb|DispWithArrows(*)|:

\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
  \begin{DispWithArrows}
    a + b = c
  \end{DispWithArrows}
\end{minipage}%
}
\bigskip

\verb|minipage| starts with an \verb|align(*)|:

\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
  \begin{align}
    a + b = c
  \end{align}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the extra vertical space before `align`, see [How to make equation spacing consistent in minipage regardless of horizontal alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456288).

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Just a question, what's the difference with/without \ifvmode? Also, is \AtBeginEnvironment part of "vanilla" LaTeX or is that provided by etoolbox?

Comment: @PurpleMyst: `\AtBeginDocument` is now in the LaTeX kernel (since 2020/10/01).

Comment: @muzimuzhi: Thanks for your analysis. I will post a new version of `witharrows` on CTAN which corrects that bug.

Comment: @PurpleMyst `\AtBeginEnvironment{...}{\ifvmode <code>\fi}` detects if the patched environment starts a new paragraph. For example in `\par \begin{DispWithArrows*}` the condition `\ifvmode` is true hence the `<code>` is used, but in `some text \begin{DispWithArrows*}` the condition is false hence the `<code>` is skipped.